# Flyback Converter Oscillator

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I am posting a small circuit I have found in a commercial power supply. It is a flyback converter transforming AC mains into 12V DC. I am having trouble understanding how transistor T1 is actually oscillating, that is switching between on and off state. I remember my brofessor saying that the auxiliary winding and R3 C1 form a positive feedback for the base of T1.

From my understanding R1 is a power up resistor to start the process of oscillation when the current is turned on. It drives a little bit of current throug the base of T1, therefore the pimary coil starts conducting and induces a current in the secondary auxiliary winding. Judging by polarity the current from the AUXiliary winding is now pushed through R3 and C1 into the base of T1 amplifying current flow. Once the inductor on the primary is fully loaded no current is induced in the auxiliary winding and therefore polarity switches and starts sucking out the current of the base of T1 through R3 C1? How does T1 ever start conducting again? I dont understand this, please give me some help, I need to pass my exam

[image: Circuit]

Comment: Did your brofessor tell you to simulate it by any chance?

Comment: The aux secondary should have the center tap line from the first transformer drawn to it so you know they are connected and the secondary isn't an inductor.

Comment: no, but if that will help i will gladly do so. Any recommendations on what to use for the simulation? I havent really simulated much except for small circuits with online simulators

Comment: 12VDC directly from a transformer secondary?

Comment: I prefer LTspice but there are plenty of options to choose from.

Comment: @Finnbar see the dots. Thats an indicator that there is still some circuitry behind it that i have left out for simplcity.

Comment: Try to read this : https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/is-this-a-class-c-amplifier.132927/page-2#post-1107738 and this http://web.archive.org/web/20180320173440/https://mmcircuit.com/understand-rcc-smps/  Any additional question?